# Django forms.media pulling media from pip installed app

Tags: python, django, django-forms, virtualenv

I have created a customized python app package which is a custom widget I can use in my Django Project. The custom widget is pip installed from my requirements.txt and can be found in my environment folder env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/custom_widget... Inside that there is a static folder with js and css files. The forms.Widget object itself is created with its own form assets.. see below:

```
    css = {
        'all': (
            'css/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css',
            'css/custom-widget.css',
        ),
    }
    js = (
        'js/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js',
        'js/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js',
        'js/custom-widget.js',
    )
```

The dataTables css and js are an older version than that of the ones in my Django Project staticfiles directory. Other locations in my Django project use newer versions of datatables. When I use the widget in an app under my project and try to include the form assets in the template with {{form.media}}, it pulls the dataTables css and js from my Django Project staticfiles directory rather than the static directory defined under my custom widget. This is a problem because they are different versions and my widget does not behave correctly. I am wondering if there is a way to pull my assets from the custom app that has been pip installed rather than from the static files defined from my settings STATICFILES_DIRS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static files app directories finder will use any matching file - you can't specify which app you want to use.

You could move the custom widgets files from `static` to `static/custom_widget`, then update the media class to include the new prefix.

```
css = {
    'all': (
        'custom_widget/css/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css',
        'custom_widget/css/custom-widget.css',
    ),
}
js = (
    'custom_widget/js/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js',
    'custom_widget/js/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js',
    'custom_widget/js/custom-widget.js',
)
```

Comment: yes thank you, the problem was that the two different DataTables js files (which were named the same) had extremely similar path names, so updating the path (by creating new folders) and the media to look into those folders was the solution